# How to Create Cases for Employee Community Users

Tags: employee-community

It seems that Employee Community licenses are different than other Community licenses as they Employee is a Salesforce User rather than a Company Contact. When creating a case, how to have the Employee Community user as the Case Contact?

Answer (score 0):

You would not able to create cases for them directly, for Employee community license the ideal way is to have a Person Account created for each of the employee and tie the User to account through the Account owner field. You can create cases against the Person account associated to the employee and get your case management working.